# Can you check my query (fastest to 10k)?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, reputation-leagues

At https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/959/fastest-to-10k

I have only played around a bit with **`data.se`** so the query could be very wrong.

I know of at least one inaccuracy

1. **downvotes (-1 a pop) are not counted/countable**, so the days taken is most likely higher

- *Possible approach is to average users.downvote over days recorded and approximate a daily downvote count*

And would appreciate feedback on

- how to improve it, if possible
- what other inaccuracies there are
- is there a deletion flag against posts, or are they not visible in the **`data.se`** dump?

Comment: nice! (no idea if it's correct though) I do feel a little humiliated!

Comment: Congrats! Ive been seeing your rep creep up every couple days (we collide every now & then in the `sql` questions). and i've had the same thought Were you are the fastest to reach 10k.

Comment: Deleted posts are not included in the dump, thus not visible in SEDE.

Comment: Yeah, he partitioned.  What u gonna do about it?

Comment: Someone made 10K faster than Jon Skeet! `:O`

Comment: @John - that means nothing though. Jon started with a young site with lower question velocity. Not sure about vote velocity though - calls for another data.se query - but most questions sit at none to very few votes nowadays (I wouldn't know about history).