# Can we add vote history to the data.se dumps?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

#### EDIT AGAIN

For everyone downvoting this request - how is this different from the data *already publicly available* from the new `/users/<id>/<name>?tab=reputation` page? At least leave an answer or comment?!

#### EDIT

Given the recent change here [Revealing voting patterns - new trend?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83548/156011) this request is not too much to ask is it?

---

Related:

- [Rep analysis using the community dump, missing information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/rep-analysis-using-the-community-dump-missing-information)
- [What information is missing from the SO community dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/what-information-is-missing-from-the-so-community-dump)

I have come across 2 queries so far that will not work using data.se:

- [Can you check my query (fastest to 10k)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79323/156011)
- [SEDE translation of Legendary badge query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80286/156011)

Given that we are already showing total `user.downvote`, can we have a table like this?

```
Table: user-vote
========================
uservoteid    identity
userid        int
vote_date     date   ** no time info = same identifiability as /user/rep page
```

It is still unidentifiable against where/when-exactly the votes were cast, but would help in various queries that test daily-aggregated rep changes.

There is some info about bounties gone missing along the same lines - since bounty offers (-ve rep) is missing from the vote table completely.  Can `vote.user_id` have the correct value for bounties (instead of null)?

Answer (score 8):

While it may be difficult to associate a person with a particular vote based only on day, it's not perfectly anonymous.

Breaking that anonymity, even at this very high level where it's hard to see anything, still requires a high bar.  I don't think these queries, and many others, bring enough to the table in terms of improving stack overflow to release this information.

Please review [Revealing voting patterns - new trend?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83548/) for one instance where voting patterns may be pulled out of such data.

Comment: Can you really associate votes to users by aggregated daily count alone?

Comment: @Richard I can't think of a way to do it, but I don't presume to know enough that I can state with 100% certainty that this is not a breach of privacy.  Witness the AOL search debacle years ago, where people were certain "anonymized" data couldn't be tracked to individuals.  Just because we can't imagine how an individual vote record (even scrubbing the time from it, and the items voted on) can be used in the future doesn't mean it can't be used as a breach of anonymity.  Regardless, the reason for releasing that information must be a *very* good reason.

Comment: But if the information to link a person's vote with a post simply does not exist...

Comment: Consider revising this answer in light of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83548/?