# Rep (bar) graph bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

Sorry Kevin (I upvoted 1 answer and downvoted another 5 for a net rep change of 0).  I was unable to use Data.SE<sup>1</sup> to find user/date combinations netting a non-0-vote, 0-rep day.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph

[image: Kevin Montrose point-in-time rep bar-graph]!

The image fails to register a bar for the day Mar 29, where Kevin in fact had 6 rep changes.  This test case has the day at the end of the graph, so maybe there's code to end the graph on the "last day in range with non-zero rep change".  My real goal was to see if the missing 0-height green bar will cause the day to be unclickable.  A 2-rep change (acceptance) still draws a sliver of a bar.

<sup>1</sup> [Request pending](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80310/can-we-add-vote-history-to-the-data-se-dumps)

Answer (score 1):

My bad - the function that copied data from the bottom graph to the top graph was leaving off the max of the selected area; today would never get plotted.

A fix will be deployed in the next build.